# Spring-boot thymeleaf load HTML file from classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a multi module project structure like :

```
- application (parent module)
--- boot (web-app)
----- src/main/resources/templates/layout.html

---- todo (jar file)
----- src/main/resources/templates/home.html
```

and on my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public String home() {
    return "todo/home";
}
```

I'm getting the error message as below:

```
Error resolving template "todo/home", template might not exist or
might not be accessible by any of the configured Template 
Resolvers]
```

Is there configuration needed to configure something specially for spring for searching templates on class path?

Comment: You could post your update as an answer to this question and accept it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding following properties solves my problem:

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```