# Sending email with Template using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, email

I have created the simple spring boot application and trying to send email using email template but its throwing:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "email-simple.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.`

I also used thymeleaf classpath in `application.properties`

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates
```

But i keep getting the same exception. Can any body know the solution pl help me. 
Below is the source code i am using.
(1) I used Thymeleaf in pom.xml
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

(2) I kept my email-simple.html file in the resources/templates/email-simple.html.

(3) here is my Service class:

```
@Component
public class SmptMailSender {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;  

 @Autowired 
 private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
 public void sendSimpleMail(final String recipientName, final String    recipientEmail, final Locale locale) 
            throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example HTML email (simple)");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email-simple.html", ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Send email
        this.javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);

    }
```

}

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29479403/3166303

Comment: The above code is works by below changes:

Comment: I got the solution by below two changes:  
(1)application.properties file – add the ‘/’ at the end of templates     
                                                      
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/  

(2)SmptMailSender class - remove the .html for "email-simple" 

Final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process(“email-simple”,ctx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Freemarker template to format your email.

[this project](https://github.com/hdineth/SpringBoot-freemaker-email-send) has complete instructions on how to do it

this uses a rest controller to get email parameters like receivers address, subject and content and send pre formatted email.

Comment: This project was very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency instead

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```