# How to use Thymeleaf to include html file into another html file

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have been looking at all of the resources available on how to include an html file into another html file using Thymeleaf's th:insert. I am wondering if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong as I feel like this html looks exactly like the examples I have seen.

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org ">
<head>
    <title>Default Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div th:insert="templates/Navbar :: navbar">  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Navbar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org ">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>NavigationBar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../css/NavBar.css" th:href="@{/css/NavBar.css}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div th:fragment="navbar" class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a th:href="@{/}" href="/home"> Home</a>
                <a th:href="@{/}" href="/help">Help</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is my project's resource hierarchy via screen shot
[image]

If I put the code between the  into the index.html and link the css file, the navbar shows up and works. So, I am not sure why the insert is not working. Here is my configuration file which has been edited based on examples below:

```
@Configuration
public class WebPageControllerConfig {

    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver;

    @Value("${WebController.startHour}")
    public String startHour;

    @Value("${WebController.endHour}")
    public String endHour;

    @Value("${WebController.numOfSkus}")
    public int numOfSkus;

    @Value("${WebController.skusToQuery}")
    public File skusToQuery;

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver webPageTemplateResolver(){
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver webPageTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        webPageTemplateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        webPageTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        webPageTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        webPageTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        webPageTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return webPageTemplateResolver;
    }

    /* Old way of trying to configure
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {...}

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver setTemplateResolver(){...}

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine setTemplateEngine() {...}

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {...}
    End of old configuration       */

    public String getStartHour() {return startHour;}

    public String getendHour() {return endHour;}

    public Object getnumOfSkus() {return numOfSkus;}

    public File getSkusToQuery(){return skusToQuery;}
}
```

Comment: It's `th:fragment`. Not `th:fragments`. Also you must use correct paths. Right now you are assuming that your html files are in the same directory but they're not.

Comment: Thanks! So, I tried the below answer and it didn't work. Then, based off not having the correct path, I changed th:insert="../templates/navbar :: navbar" to use the correct path. This also didn't work. Any further hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to

```
th:insert="templates/Navbar :: navbar"
```

and

```
th:fragment="navbar"
```

Configuration example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5 emails")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("root folder where all thymeleaf files/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I tried this, but it did not work. Are you also implying to take out class='"navbar"?

Comment: Also, with my NavBar.html file having a capital N, should it be templates/Narbar :: navbar ?

Comment: I suppose, yes. If this still not work, check your thymeleaf suffix/prefix settings.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, how to I set the Thymeleaf settings. I see in the tutorial document it talks about the Template Resolver and they use templateResolver.setPrefix and templateResolver.setSuffix, but I do not know where to set these. In my controller class?

Comment: There are different approaches. It could be @ Configuration class or properties. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479403/spring-boot-thymeleaf-load-html-file-from-classpath.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I'm going to have to ask a different question on stack overflow because I have been trying to use the @configuration class approach, but  with no success. Once I figure out how to configure my Spring MVC application, and your solution works, I can accept it as the answer.

Comment: I want to either do it using java or yaml file. I created a class SetTemplateEngine to configure this, but I cannot get it to work. I think I could also do it in the yaml file and use @value tag to configure TemplateResolver. Is that correct?

Comment: @CodyFerguson I added example with configuration from one of my projects.

Comment: Thank you, @egorlitvinenko! I used that example, but I am unable to load the Narbar fragment. As stated above, the fragment and css file create what I want when injected in index.html. I also test mapping the whole Navbar.html file which also works. However, the th:insert just doesn't insert the html fragment

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

> th:replace="/navbar::navbar"

or

> th:insert="/navbar::navbar"

It works for me. No need to specify `"template/navbar"`.