# How to configure Spring MVC using annotations

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have been struggling with creating a Spring MVC web application that uses Thymeleaf. I am not sure on the exact way to configure it using annotations. Here are my two related classes here:

webPageController.java

```
package webservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import webservice.Config.WebPageControllerConfig;

@Controller
public class webPageController {

    @Autowired
    WebPageControllerConfig webPageControllerConfig;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home( Model model){
        model.addAttribute("9", webPageControllerConfig.getstartHour());
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/help")
    public String help(String name, Model model){
        return "help";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Navbar")
    public String navbar(String name, Model model) {return "Navbar";}
}
```

WebPageControllerConfig.java

```
package webservice.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import java.io.File;

@Configuration
public class WebPageControllerConfig {
    @Value("${WebController.startHour}")
    private String startHour;

    @Value("${WebController.endHour}")
    private String endHour;

    @Value("${WebController.numOfSkus}")
    private int numOfSkus;

    @Value("${WebController.inputFile}")
    private File skusToQuery;

    public String getStartHour(){return startHour;}
}
```

I have tried many different ways to get the configuration correct. This is my latest attempt. I wanted to use the `@AutoConfiguration` annotation, but it did not work correctly. I have an application class with the `@SpringBootApplication`. I was able to run the program and load the pages corresponding to /home and /help. However, once I added
 to the home.html page, I got an error:

```
java.langlIllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean 'startHour' available as request attribute
```

So, I am not sure what I did wrong with the configuration class. Also, I am not sure how to achieve the same function as this xml [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479403/spring-boot-thymeleaf-load-html-file-from-classpath) using annotations and my configuration class. Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out how to configure this even after looking at multiple tutorials.

Edit: Here is my application.yaml which is under the resources directory.

```
WebController:
    startHour: 9:00 AM
    endHour: 12:00 PM
    numOfSkus: 100
    inputFile: null
```

Here is my home.html which is under resources/templates

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../static/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Need to change in order to fit my project -->
    <!-- <form action="#" th:action="@{/home}" th:object="${homePageController}" method="post">-->
        <h1><u>OIC GIV Comparator</u></h1>
        <strong>Start hour:</strong>
        <input type="text" value="8:00 AM" th:field="${startHour}"/>
        <strong>End hour:</strong>
        <input type="text" value="1:00 PM" th:field="${endHour}"/>
        <p><strong>Number of Skus to query (should change to file for input)</strong></p>
        <input type="number" th:field="${inputFile}"/>
        <p><strong>--or--</strong></p>
        <p><strong>Enter file of skus</strong></p>
        <input type="file" th:field="${inputFile}"/>
        <p> <button class="btn btn-default">Start</button> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, I am unsure why @Value("${WebController.starthour}") doesn't throw an error my yaml file is application.yaml

Comment: what is the content of your application.yaml

Comment: I feel stupid now. I realize that The WebController part is referencing back to my yaml which is why it doesn't throw any errors. I posted my yaml above

Comment: Now worries, this is how we all learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> @Bean
> String getStartHour(){return startHour;}
> ```

At first glance, there is potentially a couple of problems

1. `@Value("${WebController.startHour}")` is not seem correct to me. it will work only if your `application.yml` file has entry `WebController.startHour: <someNumber>`
2. remove `@Bean` annotation
3. In your controller, instead of `@Autowired private String startHour;`, do `@Autowired WebPageControllerConfig webPageControllerConfig;`
4. use webPageControllerConfig.getStartHour()
5. `model.addAttribute("9", webPageControllerConfig.getstartHour());` doesn't make much sense to me.. 
   change it to `model.addAttribute("startHour", webPageControllerConfig.getStartHour());`
   and add 
   `model.addAttribute("endHour", webPageControllerConfig.getEndHour());` `model.addAttribute("inputFile", 1);`

Comment: So, I updated my question with what you suggested. I am still receiving the same error, however.

Comment: Yea I was trying to add the variable to the model with a default value of 9. So, I commented out model.addAttribute("9", webPageControllerConfig.getStartHour());

Comment: You still see the same error or error message changed?

Comment: Yea, it's the same error. Could this be from not configuring the properties spring thymeleaf prefix and/or suffix?

Comment: try adding model.addAttribute("startHour", webPageControllerConfig.getStartHour()); and model.addAttribute("endHour", webPageControllerConfig.getEndHour()); and model.addAttribute("inputFile", 1);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155044/discussion-between-so-random-dude-and-cody-ferguson).